# React Navigation: Bottom Tabs style

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

How to apply a style on the bottom tab so that it looks similar to this model?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig4pn.png)

```
<HomeTabs.Navigator
        screenOptions={({route})=>({
            tabBarIcon: ({color, size})=>{
                const {name} = icons[route.name]
                return <Ionicons name={name} size={size} color={color}/>
            }
        })}
        tabBarOptions={
            {
                style: {
                    height: 50,
                    width: 300,
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    elevation: 2,
                    borderTopStartRadius: 5,
                    borderTopEndRadius: 5,

                },
                activeTintColor: '#845EC2',
            }
        }
    >
```

result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx6QP.png)

There is no such container

Comment: Not entirely sure what your code is but you need to add margins in barStyle prop of your Navigator. If you post the code you have I can help you get it matching the image

Comment: Any solution to this ?

Comment: @Aousafrashid The solution was to use absolute position in the tab navigatior

Answer (score 4):

**tabBarStyle** worked for me.
Refer official documentation for more styling options [click here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#scenecontainerstyle).

```
<Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                    let iconName;
    
                    if (route.name === 'Home') {
                        iconName = focused? 'ios-home-sharp': 'ios-home-outline';
                    } else if (route.name === 'Favourites') {
                        iconName = focused ? 'ios-heart-sharp' : 'ios-heart-outline';
                    }
                   
                    // You can return any component that you like here!
                    return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
                },
                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#58ceb2',
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                //Tab bar styles can be added here
                tabBarStyle:{paddingVertical: 5,borderTopLeftRadius:15,borderTopRightRadius:15,backgroundColor:'white',position:'absolute',height:50},
                tabBarLabelStyle:{paddingBottom:3},
            })}
          >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Favourites" component={FavouritesScreen} />
            
          </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with since there is no code. Hope this can help.

```js
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();


const Navigator = () => {
  return (

  <NavigationContainer>

  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Something"
    barStyle={{ marginLeft:10, marginRight:10 }} //This is where you can manipulate its look. 
    >


    <Tab.Screen name="firstOne" component={Something1}/>

    <Tab.Screen name="secondOne" component={Something2}/>

    <Tab.Screen name="thirdOne" component={Something3}/>

  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

  );
}
```

Note the `barStyle` prop. That's where you can change how the bottom bar displays.

Comment: This barStyle is not prop

Comment: oh, you use the materialBottomTabs

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with:

```
const screenOptionStyle = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.darkGrey,
  },
  headerTintColor: Colors.richGold,
  headerBackTitle: "",
  tabBarStyle: [{ backgroundColor: Colors.darkGrey }], <--- HERE
};

 <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
```

Comment: For someone reason screenOptions only gets applied to 1 out of my 3 tabs

Answer (score 0):

try this
add tabbaroptions
example

```
<tab.navigation tabbaroptions={{barstyle : styles.container}} >
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please properly format your code example?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works!

```
const Navigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{style:{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}}> //do styling here
    <Tab.Screen/>
    <Tab.Screen/>
    <Tab.Screen/>
  </Tab.Navigator>
)

export default Navigator;
```